# Code to detect current page

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a php or javascript code that can detect the current user's page and then add `<a class="active">` to an item in a `ul` (my menu).  I include my menu in my pages with `PHP include` so making change is easy; I only have to edit it once.  But, with that method, I can't individually set each page to have `a class="active"`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Why cant you set each page to have a class="active"? Which specific pages do you want it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what I usually do is set a variable before I include the header, like

```
$current = "home";
```

And then in the header I'd have an if statement in each link

```
<a href="/home" <?php if ( $current == "home" ) { echo "class='active'" } ?>>Home</a>
```

Could be ways to improve it, but it's simple if your menu isn't too big.

Answer (score 2):

You several options, e.g.,

- The part that handles navigations can read the request URI directly. This can be done by reading `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (don't forget this may include the query string).
- At some point, you must know what page you're on, because you decide which content you display based on that. You can define a function that handles the navigation markup and pass it the name of the current page so that it knows which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can look at the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

In JavaScript, you can examine `window.location`.

Comment: I'm not that great with either of those languages.  How exactly would I do that?